# How Stochastic Binary Neurons works with rectified linear (or Linear threshold) case?

Tags: neural-networks, stochastic-processes, linear

I'm taking a course in [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks/lecture/o9bIJ/some-simple-models-of-neurons-8-min) about neural networks.

I understand the relation and difference between "Sigmoid Neurons" and "Stochastic Binary Neurons", but I don't how could you adapt "Rectified Linear" to Stochastic. They said you could imaging the output:

$$ \texttt{z} = b + \sum_i (x_i * w_i) \\
\text{(where } b \text{ is bias, }x \text{ the i}^{th}\text{ input, a }w \text{ the i}^{th}\text{ weight)}$$

as the rate of spike, and then use this as the lambda parameter of a poisson process.

How does this work?

If I want to know the probability of having a spike, I need to define 
$$X \approx P \,(\lambda * \delta t)$$

and calculate $P\,(X=1)$?

What would be a correct $\delta t$? 1?